# XML attribute value not getting fetched

Tags: android, xml, android-asynctask, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse the XML file below :

```
<current>
<city id="1273840" name="Connaught Place">
<coord lon="77.22" lat="28.63"/>
<country>IN</country>
<sun rise="2016-04-11T00:29:24" set="2016-04-11T13:15:01"/>
</city>
<temperature value="308.15" min="308.15" max="308.15" unit="kelvin"/>
<humidity value="17" unit="%"/>
<pressure value="1010" unit="hPa"/>
```

I am successfully able to get the value of country tag("IN") but not able to get the value of attribute "value" or any value of attribute for temperature,pressure or any other tags mentioned above.I am getting null as the value.
Following is the code I have written:

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            URL u = new URL(URL);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            con.setReadTimeout(10000);
            con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.connect();
            InputStream i = con.getInputStream();
            xf = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            xp = xf.newPullParser();
            xp.setInput(i, null);
            xp.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES,false);
            event = xp.getEventType();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            while(event!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
              name=xp.getName();

                switch(event){

                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                            text=xp.getText();
                            break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                        if(name.equals("country")){
                            country=text;
                            break;
                        }

                         else if(name.equals("temperature")){
                            temperature=xp.getAttributeValue(null,"value");
                            publishProgress(temperature);
                            break;
                            }
                        else
                        break;
                        }
                try {
                    event=xp.next();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Can someone please help me understand the issue here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the attibute you should do it in the start tag where is the value. Something similar as this:

```
String mAttribute;
//......

case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
mAttribute = xp.getAttributeValue(null,"value");
    break;
case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
        text=xp.getText();
        break;
case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

    if(name.equals("country")){
        country=text;
        break;
    }

     else if(name.equals("temperature")){
        temperature=mAttribute;
        publishProgress(temperature);
        break;
        }
    else
    break;
    }
//.....
```

Comment: Thanks.this solved the issue..but I am curious as to why the end tag option is not working as in your case also I am storing the value in mattribute and then assigning it in the End tag..

Comment: this <temperature value="308.15" min="308.15" max="308.15" unit="kelvin"/> is like <temperature value="308.15" min="308.15" max="308.15" unit="kelvin"></temperature>, as you can see the end tag don't have any attribute